# Docker how to send request(curl - get, post) one container to another container

Tags: http, docker

GET(and POST PUT ....) request using curl in one container to another.

**$ docker ps**

```
CONTAINER ID    IMAGE      COMMAND       PORTS                                           NAMES
b184219cd8f6    otp_totp  "./run.sh"    0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp                           totp_api
c381c276593f    service   "/bin/sh -c"  0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp   service
d0add6b1c72e    mysql     "/tmp/run.sh" 0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp                           mysql
```

when I send request `curl -X GET http://localhost.3000` to `totp_api container` in local

`totp_api` return `{'status':200}`

but I want send request in `service` container

like// `curl -X GET http://localhost:3000` to `totp_api` container in `service`(docker exec -it /bin/bash), `totp_api` will return `{'status':200}` to `server` container

```
project_folder
             ㄴ- docker-compose.yml # service, mysql container
api_folder
         ㄴ- docker-compose.yml # totp_api container
```

please some body tell me some advice

---

### after

**api/folder/docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
    totp:
        build: .
        container_name: totp_api
        volumes:
            - $PWD:/home
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        tty: true
        restart: always
        networks:
            - bridge

networks:
    bridge:
        driver: bridge
```

-

```
$ docker-compose up -d
$ docker network ls

NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
4a05be5e600f        bridge              bridge              local
503d0586c7ec        host                host                local
########            ####
727bfc6cc21f        otp_bridge          bridge              local
########            ####
3c19d98d9ca5        otp_default         bridge              local
```

-

```
$ docker network inspect otp_bridge

[
    {
        "Name": "otp_bridge",
        "Id": "727bfc6cc21fd74f19eb7fe164582637cbad4c2d7e36620c1c0a1c51c0490d31",
        "Created": "2017-12-13T06:12:40.5070258Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
                "Driver": "default",
                "Options": null,
                "Config": [
                    {
                        "Subnet": "172.19.0.0/16",
                        "Gateway": "172.19.0.1"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Internal": false,
            "Attachable": true,
            "Ingress": false,
            "ConfigFrom": {
                "Network": ""
            },
            "ConfigOnly": false,
            "Containers": {
        "02fa407062cdd5f6f368f2d17c5e68d2f9155d1d9b30c9edcbb2386a9ded648a": {
                "Name": "totp_api",
                "EndpointID": "860c47da1e70d304399b42917b927a8cc6717b86c6d1ee6f065229e33f496c2f",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "bridge",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "otp"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [docker networking](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/) and the [network commands](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/work-with-networks/), you can make sure those containers are part of the same network.

A side-effect of that unique network will be container A will know of container B name: from `totp_api`, you can ping or curl the `service` container with its name:

```
ping service
```

You can:

- do it statically in the docker compose file (and relaunch new containers), - test it out at runtime, adding existing running containers to a new network

Comment: @MinHan Yes: create a network and add your running containers to it.

Comment: ummmm , first I add network in totp_api's compose.yml...(edit question) did i get your advice right?

Comment: Yes, you can do it statically in the docker compose file, but you can also test it out at runtime, adding existing running containers to a new network.

Comment: thank you! I solved my problem! thank you very much!

Comment: Slightly off topic, but useful - if you want to curl from the host machine (for testing curl result easily) you can expose ports like this 127.0.0.1:3000:3000. Generally wouldn’t advise this in production environments though.